# Tensorflow: What is difference of tf.constant(2) and 2

Tags: tensorflow

I just started learning Tensorflow by myself. I got a question, what is the difference between following code?

```
x = tf.add(3,5)
```

and

```
a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(5)
x = tf.add(a,b)
```

The `print(sess.run(x))` both return 8. So what difference does it make of using `tf.constant`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not make any difference.

Each time a tensorflow operation expects a `Tensor` input but receives something else, it tries to convert it with [`tf.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor), and if successful, proceeds normally with that output.

In case of a constant like `2`, but also `np.array`s, `lists`, `tuple`s, or virtually any container or (well-formed) hierarchy of containers, `tf.convert_to_tensor` will create a `Const` operation, just like the one you would create by hand by calling `tf.constant`.

`tf.constant` is nonetheless useful because it allows you, among other things, to name your constant in the graph and to control its data type (with `name` and `dtype` arguments respectively).